# scrollbar not working when I add absolute position to innerdiv

Tags: html, css, position, overflow

overflow-y scrollbar not working when I add position:absolute to .divwidth.

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zd9mxa5r/)

```
.overflow {
  width:80%;
  margin-left:10%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.divwidth {
  width:100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
```

Comment: add 'position:relative;' to outer div

Comment: @Toxide82 : https://jsfiddle.net/zd9mxa5r/3/

Comment: That's because one of the `paragraph` is beneath `divwidth`. But if you keep adding more content then the vertical scrollbar will appear again.

Comment: @Hewlett : thats right. But, I want to move the .divwidth when i scroll .overflow div. but, its not https://jsfiddle.net/zd9mxa5r/9/

Comment: @Hewlett : .divwidth div keeps staying on the same area when I scroll.

Comment: If you want to move .divwidth during scroll then you have to use JS. If that's so then I recommend you update your question, and also add the tag JavaScript. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this one:You can add `position: absolute;` from `.overflow` class file

```
.overflow {
  width:80%;
  margin-left:10%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}
.divwidth {
  width:100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #666;
  position: relative;

}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/zd9mxa5r/5/)

OR

```
.overflow {
  width:80%;
  margin-left:10%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
.divwidth {
  width:100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/zd9mxa5r/8/)

Comment: but innerdiv .divwidth should be infront of .overflow div

Answer (score 0):

so if you add it to the overflow one

```
.overflow {
 position: relative;
 width:80%;
 margin-left:10%;
 height: 300px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 background: #333;
 color: #fff;
}
```

That way the inner divs absolute dimensions will be restricted to this div

Comment: check here https://jsfiddle.net/zd9mxa5r/3/ . scrollbar not working also innerdiv .divwidth should be infront of .overflow div